# How do I interpret this question?

Tags: regular-languages

For any language $L \subset \Sigma^*$, define $S(L)$ to be $$\{x\in L \mid \neg \exists y \in L: \exists z \in \Sigma^*: (z \ne \epsilon) \land (x=yz)  \}$$

Show that $S(L) = S(S(L))$

I'm confused about the question here. The way we define $S(L)$ takes elements from $L$ $(x \mid x \in L)$, but $x=yz$ and $y \notin L$. How is it possible for x to concatenate an element from $\bar{L}$ (complement of $L$ since $y \notin L$) and still be an element of $L$?

Comment: $\lnot\exists y \in L$ does not mean $\exists y \in \bar{L}$ -- I think you are being confused by that.

Comment: @chi, how does this negation works here?

Comment: Negation works as usual. Just think about a property of $x$ stating "there exist $y$ and $z$, with $y\in L$, such that ..." and take those $x\in L$ making the property false (meaning that there are no such $y$ and $z$).

Comment: @chi, $S(L) = \{ x \in L: \forall y \in L. \forall z \in \Sigma*. (z = \epsilon) \lor (x \ne yz)\}$. Is the statement correct? So the proof of $S(S(L)) \subset S(L)$ would be trivia; because elements in $S(S(L))$ are taken from $S(L)$

Comment: Yes, even if in my mind "not exist $x,y$ such that ... and .." is simpler to understand than your "or" (disjunction). And yes, that inclusion is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The formula means "it is not true that there exists $y \in L$ and $z \in \Sigma^*$ such that $z \ne \epsilon$ and $x=yz$."  That is, there is no way of writing $x=yz$ such that $y\in L$ and $z\neq\epsilon$.

Comment: Looks like $S(L)$ removes the common prefixes.

Comment: @DeepJoshi No, it removes the strings that have prefixes in the language. The language definition doesn't talk about properties shared by strings, so it's not about common anything.

Answer (score -1):

$S(L)$ = $$\{ x\in L: \forall y \in L. \forall z \in \Sigma*. (z \ne \epsilon) \land (x \ne yz)   \}$$

$S(L)$ is all strings $x \in L$ which don't have non-trivial prefixes $y \in L$

Comment: not sure why is that $(z \ne \epsilon) \land ( x \ne yz)$; I thought since we negation the statement; we should also negate the last statement; so that it because $(z = \epsilon) \lor (x \ne yz)$

Comment: Negation binds tightly to $y$, it's not for the entire statement. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: This is incorrect. You've just defined $S(L)=\emptyset$, since it is not true that, for all $z\in\Sigma^*$, $z\neq\epsilon$. "Negation binds tightly to $y$" doesn't make sense. Negation is applied to formulae, not variables.

Comment: Please check this for order or precedence https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1150782/298196